# Register all interfaces of COM DLL using C++ API

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com

I know, we can register interfaces of COM DLL using regsvr32.exe

is any windows C++ API available, Which API will register interfaces of COM DLL.

Thanks!
Vijay Kumbhani

Comment: Regsvr32.exe is about the simplest program you can think of.  It uses LoadLibrary() to load the DLL and GetProcAddress() to find the DllRegisterServer export.  And calls it, that's all.  No api is provided because it is so simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `regsvr32` does is load a dll and call the [DllRegisterServer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682162(v=vs.85).aspx) function exposed by the DLL.

If you want to write your own code to do this then you need to use [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) and [GetProcAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx) to get a pointer to the function, and then just call it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the CLSID and COM dll file path?
If yes, you can write them into registry with API RegCreateKeyEx/SetKeyValue/RegCreateKeyEx/..., here is a example:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{CLSID}\InprocServer32]
@="C:\\Windows\\System32\\oleaut32.dll"    
"ThreadingModel"="Both"

LONG lreturn = RegCreateKeyEx(
        HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
        _T("CLSID\${COMCLSID}"),  // subkey
        0,                        // reserved
        NULL,                     // class string (can be NULL)
        REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
        KEY_ALL_ACCESS,
        NULL,                     // security attributes
        &hKey,
        NULL                      // receives the "disposition" (is it a new or existing key)
        );
hr = __HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(lreturn);
// The default key value is a description of the object.
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = SetKeyValue(hKey, NULL, _T("your description"));
}

// Create the "InprocServer32" subkey
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    const TCHAR *sServer = TEXT("InprocServer32");

    LONG lreturn = RegCreateKeyEx(hKey, sServer, 0, NULL,
        REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hSubkey, NULL);

    hr = __HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(lreturn);
}

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = SetKeyValue(hSubkey, NULL, _T("${COM DLL file Path}"));
}

// Add a new value to the subkey, for "ThreadingModel" = <threading model>
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = SetKeyValue(hSubkey, TEXT("ThreadingModel"), sThreadingModel);
}
```